# Downloading 1000s of images using php , how to bypass blank images

Tags: php

I have a php file that is creating a list of url paths of images i want to download. Currently i have just been creating a list , copying and pasting it in a desktop app that will download images by url list in txt file. I wanted to go ahead and add the download to the php file to bypass that current step.

currently the following generates a list of urls i use to copy and paste to desktop downloader app

```
foreach ($espn_ar as $key => $value) echo 'ht'.'tps://a.espncdn.com/i/headshots/nfl/players/full/'.$espn_ar[$key].'.png<br>';
```

the list that is generated looks like this , with approximately 2500 url paths

```
https://a.espncdn.com/i/headshots/nfl/players/full/2580.png
https://a.espncdn.com/i/headshots/nfl/players/full/2330.png
https://a.espncdn.com/i/headshots/nfl/players/full/2977742.png
https://a.espncdn.com/i/headshots/nfl/players/full/5528.png
https://a.espncdn.com/i/headshots/nfl/players/full/5529.png
https://a.espncdn.com/i/headshots/nfl/players/full/5536.png
https://a.espncdn.com/i/headshots/nfl/players/full/5713.png
https://a.espncdn.com/i/headshots/nfl/players/full/8439.png
https://a.espncdn.com/i/headshots/nfl/players/full/8461.png
https://a.espncdn.com/i/headshots/nfl/players/full/8479.png
```

To bypass the step of copying and pasting to a desktop app , i added the following

```
foreach ($espn_ar as $key => $value) {
    $url = 'ht' . 'tps://a.espncdn.com/i/headshots/nfl/players/full/' . $espn_ar[$key] . '.png';
    $img = 'images/' . $espn_ar[$key] . '.png';
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    $fp = fopen($img, 'wb');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

This seems to be working to download all images into a directory setup called "images"

Question 1 - is what i have done the best method for what i'm trying to achieve ?

Question 2 - when using the desktop app it doesn't download a blank image if the url path doesn't contain an image, however using the php method it does download a blank image if one of the url paths doesn't contain any image, so how can i add something to not download a blank png file, or only download files over 1kb, or delete all files 1kb or smaller after all files downloaded, not sure what is best way to handle that.

Comment: Reading [the `curl_exec` documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php) it has a paragraph saying "Note that response status codes which indicate errors (such as 404 Not found) are not regarded as failure. `curl_getinfo()` can be used to check for these." So perhaps check [`curl_getinfo`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php) to get the status of the response might be a good start?

Comment: you might be hitting a rate limit. i suggest you do this in batches of 100 images every minute

Comment: as a novice in php , any visual edits to what i currently have would be appreciated. I'm just googling and reading and trying to do this myself with very little knowledge of php. Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> is what i have done the best method for what i'm trying to achieve ?

Answers to such kind of questions are generally based on your explanation of 'best'. Since you said you have very little knowledge of php, I just guess you want a simple approach, and the simplest approach I can find is:

```
file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($url));
```

Notice that you should set `allow_url_fopen = On` and enable openssl (`extension=openssl`) in `php.ini`.

Here is a full example:

```
foreach ($espn_ar as $value) {
    $url = "https://a.espncdn.com/i/headshots/nfl/players/full/$value.png";
    $img = "images/$value.png";
    $content = file_get_contents($url);
    file_put_contents($img, $content);
}
```

---

> when using the desktop app it doesn't download a blank image if the url path doesn't contain an image, however using the php method it does download a blank image if one of the url paths doesn't contain any image, so how can i add something to not download a blank png file, or only download files over 1kb , or delete all files 1kb or smaller after all files downloaded, not sure what is best way to handle that.

Because I can't check all the URLs, I guess these blank images may be caused by 404 error, or the images are really blank. I'll check them all.

```
    $content = file_get_contents($url);
    
    # download failed
    if($content === false)
        continue;
    
    # 404 error
    if(strpos($http_response_header[0], '404 Not Found') !== false)
        continue;

    # size < 1kb
    if(strlen($content) < 1024)
        continue;

    file_put_contents($img, $content);
```

Comment: this seemed to work perfectly , no blank images being downloaded , thanks !

Comment: How would i increase limit to 5kb  if(strlen($content1) < 1024)  , would it simply be if(strlen($content1) < 1024*5)  ?

Comment: You are right, 1024 * 5

Comment: I don't think the check for blank images is sufficient; just generate a huge white bitmap.